# Area under the spectral curve?

Tags: raster, r, hyperspectral-sensor

There is an existing similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638462/r-image-of-a-pixel-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1) that I have tried but didn't give me what I need.

I have an image with 20 spectral bands.  How do I compute the area under the spectral curve that is bounded by the x (wavelength), y (reflectance) and the curve itself?

```
img <- brick("sample.tif")
a <- as.array(img)
```

I was thinking of making an array of the values, then maybe from that I could compute the area as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954507/calculate-the-area-under-a-curve?noredirect=1&lq=1).  However, I just do not know how to proceed, with the many columns of spectral bands I have.